# Cache Google Calendar Events from PHP API GET Request

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I am using the google-api-php-client (API v3) to display a list of events from my Google Calendar on a page. It is working, however I would like to cache the results locally on the disk so I don't have to make an API call every time the page is loaded (the calendar doesn't change much). Is it possible to cache the results?

There is a file called Google_FileCache.php which has a Google_FileCache() class that looks like it might do what I want, but I can't find any documentation for it at all, has anyone used it?

Here is my code so far:

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';
session_start();
$CLIENT_ID = '{my client ID}';
$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME = '{my service account name}';
$KEY_FILE = '{my p12 key file}';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Public Calendar");
$client->setUseObjects(true);
if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}
$key = file_get_contents($KEY_FILE);
$client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(
    $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"),
    $key)
);
$client->setClientId($CLIENT_ID);
$service = new Google_CalendarService($client);
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}
$rightNow = date('c');
$params = array('singleEvents' => 'true', 'orderBy' => 'startTime', 'timeMin' => $rightNow);
$events = $service->events->listEvents('primary', $params);
foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {
    echo '<p>'.$event->getSummary().'</p>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this excelent piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just and FYI for everyone else looking how to do this. I figured out how to use the Google_FileCache class to cache the returned GET request. Below is my solution:

```
// Files to make API Call
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';
// Files to cache the API Call
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/cache/Google_Cache.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/cache/Google_FileCache.php';
// Google Developer info for gmail.com Service API account
$CLIENT_ID = '{My Client ID}';
$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME = '{My Service Account Name}';
// Make sure you keep your key.p12 file in a secure location, and isn't readable by others.
$KEY_FILE = '{My .p12 Key File}';
$client = new Google_Client(); // Start API call
$client->setApplicationName("Public Calendar");
$client->setUseObjects(true); // Need this to return it as an object array
// Checking to see that we are authenticated (OAuth2) to make API to calendar
if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
 $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}
// Load the key in PKCS 12 format (you need to download this from the Google API Console when the service account was created.)
$key = file_get_contents($KEY_FILE);
$client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(
    $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"),
    $key)
);
$client->setClientId($CLIENT_ID); // Set client ID for my API call
$service = new Google_CalendarService($client); // Start API call to Calendar
//Save authentication token in session
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}
// Start Caching service
$cache = new Google_FileCache();
$cache_time = 43200; // 12 hours
// If cache is there & younger than 12 hours then load cached data
if($cache->get('events_cache', $cache_time)) {
    $events = $cache->get('events_cache');
    $file_status = "cached";
}
else {
    //If it is not then make Calendar API request to Google and get the results
    $rightNow = date('c');
    $params = array('singleEvents' => 'true', 'orderBy' => 'startTime', 'timeMin' => $rightNow, 'maxResults' => 5);
    $events = $service->events->listEvents('primary', $params);
    $cache->set('events_cache', $events); // Save results into cache
    $file_status = "live";
}
// Start collecting info to be returned
echo '<!-- '.$file_status.' -->'; // So I can tell if the results are cached or not
echo '<ul class="events">';
foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {
    // Make link to event and list event name
    echo '<li><a href="'.$event->getHtmlLink().'">'.$event->getSummary().'</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: It would be better if google could provide an lightweight API call to see if there have been any changes or not since the last API call and then we could use this if there hadn't been.